# Unncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined base.js remote.js YouTube scripts in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube

When visiting a page with an embedded YouTube video or Google Analytics in Google Chrome (I use Version 59.0.3071.109 (Official Build) (64-bit)), the browser console starts to repeat the following sequence without stopping:

```
Unncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.g.p (base.js:30)
    at remote.js:85
    at remote.js:168
g.p @ base.js:30
(anonymous) @ remote.js:85
(anonymous) @ remote.js:168
```

The URLs of the scripts are (the ID bit varies):

https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vflAQ2ruD/sk_SK/remote.js
https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-vflppxuSE/sk_SK/base.js

This does not happen in Edge or in Chrome Incognito, but it does happen when Chrome is started with plugins and extensions disabled in normal mode.

Is there a way to find out what's calling these scripts, given that the tab becomes very unresponsive as soon as it's loaded?